# Kernel SHAP loss function

Tags: shap

I'm a beginner at data science and currently learning for XAI using Kernel SHAP method.

After reading the official paper, I've found this formula to implement Kernel SHAP :

(I'm aware there are shap library, but I want to learn it first by understanding the paper)

[image: SHAP kernel Loss function]

I understand most of it, except for g(z').

What is g(z')? and how it can give a "value" or help the loss function.

I'm really sorry if what I'm asking is a foolish question, but I'm just clueless about this.
(I would appreciate it if you can give me a simple example)

Thank you!